# local and online database with android, and windows

Tags: android, database, web-services, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to have a database as a file (.db) I want to be able to have a online version of this file that can be queried through a webservice

MYsql is out of the question because it cannot be stored as a file on android or windows (needs a local server)

sqlite seems like the best option, but I do not see any "good" webservice utilities for it that can do all the basic SQL functionally with queries

am I missing a type of database that works for my multi os setup? am I missing a webservice that will work with sqllite?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a webservice to query the online DB then you really don't care of the format that online database has from the client's perspective.

So you could use a MySQL DB for the online part, and expose it through your webservice ( Since this a very common approach I'm sure you could find some resources online to help you with this task), then on the device use a SQLite to store the db locally.

One way to see it is that MYSQL is a superset of SQLite and the only thing you have to make sure is to limit the scope of queries you can do on your MYSQL db through your webservice (this is not exactly accurate but just a way of seeing it)

This [link](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/developing-RESTful-android-apps.html) explains some recommended architectures to do something very similar to what you are suggesting, from the Android side of things

Comment: Thanks for info... Another thing I should have mentioned is that the online database will need to be "downloaded" for offline use on different platforms... 

example:
This is like a library of specific tools... a user can use a certain subset of tools, they go online download a subset and then there device can use anything in there offline location

advanced users can also commit to the database new tools, so they need the offline storage and also the ability to add to the databases online